# Disabling *No visible @interface* error for unit test target

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, compiler-errors

I have a category (on `NSDate`) that contains a method that is only called from another method within the category, so there is no need to expose the method in the category's header file.

However, as expected, if I call the method from a unit test, the compiler shouts that

> No visible @interface for 'NSDate' declares the selector 'myMethod:'

I'd like to be able to turn off these particular errors (for the unit test target only, of course).

Can someone point me in the direction of the correct compiler flag?

Comment: Any downvoter care to comment on what I can do to improve the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of turning them off why not just redeclare it? If you turn the warnings off completely then you lose the fact that the compiler will give you warnings in genuine places.

So just declare it above the unit test

```
@interface NSDate (UnitTests)

// your method sig

@end

@implementation YourUnitTest

//...
```

Comment: Brilliant... I can see where you got those 10.8k points from!!

Comment: FWIW, I was only interested in turning the errors off in the unit test target. Compiling the regular target would still have highlighted them. Moot point now though.

Comment: I still think this is the safer bet. You still write code in your unit tests, so you can still make mistakes - let the compiler work for you at detecting the obvious mistakes.