# UIView with UIBezierPath with reversing path

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to give some mask at bottom view using `UIBezierPath` with `addCurve()` method.

Expected Result

[image]

Current Output

[image]

**What I have tried** is:

```
        viewHeader.backgroundColor = headerColor
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let cpoint1 = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 160)
        let cpoint2 = CGPoint(x: 280, y: viewHeader.Height + 50)
        path.move(to:.init(x: 0, y: viewHeader.Height + 10))
        path.addCurve(to: .init(x: viewHeader.Width, y: 205), controlPoint1: cpoint1, controlPoint2: cpoint2)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.reversing().cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = headerColor?.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        viewHeader.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: Hi
you need to add 3 more line to complete the box, 1. right straight line down from end of the curve, 2. bottom line right to left edge, 3. left bottom back to curve start position.

Comment: @Ammaiappan : Thanks for quik responce. As I'm new to graphics, can you please provide some code, ref regarding to this.

Comment: @iSwifter Really? You couldn't try yourself first?

Comment: @AshleyMills: I have tried. but didn't success.

Comment: In future, you should update your question to show what you've tried and where you're still having problems, rather than just ask for "some code".

Comment: @AshleyMills: I had already added that details in question. What I have tried. I didn't get idea from Ammaiappan's comment. That's why I have askd for some code.

Comment: @AshleyMills : Remember that day when you were just fresher and don't know how to do so tasks . I'm in that state now. So please dont criticise me now. If you don't want to help It's Fine. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11724880/8719510

Comment: I see you're upset, so I'm not going argue with you about this. I'd just say that rather than digging your heels in, take a tip from someone who has some experience with SO. The more effort you put in yourself, the more likely you are to have your questions answered. You managed to write code in your initial question that created a path, moved to a point and added a curve, so it wouldn't seem unreasonable for you to _attempt_ to add the extra couple of lines required to implement @Ammaiappan's pretty detailed suggestion. The more you try, the more you will learn.

Comment: @AshleyMills: Yes, you were right, I was upset. First of all sorry for rude language, please forgive me. And thanks for your comments/thoughts. I'll take care next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it ll work for you, enjoy.

```
func drawLine() {
    let headerColor = UIColor.red
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let cpoint1 = CGPoint(x: viewHeader.frame.width/4, y: 160)
    let cpoint2 = CGPoint(x: viewHeader.frame.width*3/4, y: viewHeader.frame.height + 50)
    path.move(to:.init(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to:.init(x: 0, y: viewHeader.frame.height - 50))
    path.addCurve(to: .init(x: viewHeader.frame.width, y: viewHeader.frame.height - 50), controlPoint1: cpoint1, controlPoint2: cpoint2)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewHeader.frame.width, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.close()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.reversing().cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = headerColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor =  headerColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    viewHeader.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Working.

Comment: Hi, @Ammaiappan Is it possible to get in Objective-C?

Comment: @MihirOza: Do it yourself. Swift to Obj-C is not big deal.